# How do I run index.php in a private folder from index.html

Tags: php, private, public, public-html

I have a website that has a root html at index.html. I want to redirect index.html to a php file in a private folder one parent above to run an index.php. This file would then render the html content that I need depending on the request. How would I go about this process of getting the index.php from the index.html.
The file structure looks like this:

```
private/
   -index.php

public_html/ 
   -index.html
```

Comment: You need to have `index.php` somewhere that your webserver knows about, otherwise it cannot redirect.

Comment: Isn't there a way to reference the file on the web server so that I can make everything in the public_html visible and public but everything in the private folder invisible? In other words, when I go to index.html I just want it to redirect to "../private/index.php". Why is this not possible?

Comment: There is a way, but in order to set it up `private/index.php` needs to be somewhere that it mapped from your webserver so that it can make it "private" (that is, if someone browses http://yoursite.com/private/index.php they get a nasty error page). If it isn't inside your `DocumentRoot`, then there is nothing the webserver can do - it is effectively unreachable from the web. To keep it like you have and then load the contents of `private/index.php`, you would need to write _another_ script in `public_html`, but this is just creating a solution for a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: That is exactly what I ended up doing. It's not the most elegant solution but it works. Out of curiosity, do you care if someone sees your index.php file or generally is it not a concern?

Comment: <?php include(../private/index.php); ?>  ??????? or you could even <iframe> it.

why does index.php NEED to be the url?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this meta code in your index.html

```
 <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=/private/index.php">
```

It's an html redirection actually.

If this doesn't work, try to hook in htaccess

Comment: I didn't work. I found a small and ugly work around. I use the html and redirect using the <meta> tag to a direct.php which then loads the private index php. It's not the prettiest but it works. Thanks for the help.